# King of Tokyo (2016 version): Battery Monster and Friend of Children

Tags: king-of-tokyo

In the 2nd edition of King of Tokyo (2016 version), the *Battery Monster* Power Card states:

> (Keep) When you buy *Battery Monster*, put 6 [energy symbol] on it from the bank. At the start of each turn **take 2 [energy symbol] off and add them to your pool.** When there are no [energy symbol] left discard this card.

The *Friend of Children* Power Card states:

> (Keep) When you gain any [energy symbol] **gain 1 extra [energy symbol].**

If you have *Friend of Children* and buy *Battery Monster*, does this then mean that you get 3 energy cubes each turn for the next three turns? I am unsure about this because *Battery Monster* does not explicitly say "gain energy". On the other hand, other Power cards like

> We're only making it stronger (Keep): When you lose 2 [heart symbol] or more gain 1 [energy symbol].

and

> Metamorph (Keep): At the end of your turn you can **discard any KEEP cards you have to gain their full cost in [energy symbol].**

do explicitly say "gain" so I would expect that these two cards synergize with *Friend of Children*?

Comment: Is King of Tokyo 2016 significantly different from the original? I'm wondering if we should create a new tag for it, like we did for [robo-rally] and [robo-rally-2016].

Comment: From my own limited perspective since I only have the 2016 version, looking at boardgamegeek posts only a few Power Cards have been changed significantly (like Battery Monster for example, because it was overpowered). Most are identical and some have been made more clear (e.g. Acid Attack). There are some other minor changes in the rulebook to further avoid ambiguities with other Power Cards (one example is Healing Ray: monsters in Tokyo cannot use this card since it now clearly states that in Tokyo you cannot use heart dice except for evolutions).

Comment: That sounds like comparable differences to different versions of Talisman or Axis & Allies, and we only have one tag for those. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't because the card does not say to gain the energy but to transfer it from the card to your pool so you are not gaining but moving so it is available.

Battery Monster:

> (Keep) When you buy Battery Monster, put 6 [energy symbol] on it from the bank. At the start of each turn take 2 [energy symbol] off and add them to your pool. When there are no [energy symbol] left discard this card.

The Friend of Children Power Card states:

> (Keep) When you gain any [energy symbol] gain 1 extra [energy symbol].

Answer (score 1):

For Friend of Children to take effect, the card ability that triggers it needs to specifically be a "gain".

This has been officially clarified by the designer of the game originally in French, but the English translation can be found in [this FAQ from BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/743476/faq-english-answered-gabriel-iello-french-forum).

Comment: I thought this FAQ referred to the 1st edition of King of Tokyo although many Power Cards are identical of course. For example, the Metamorph Power Card has been slightly changed in the 2nd edition and now explicitly includes the word "gain".

Comment: It does refer to the first edition, but in my opinion the clarification on gains is still relevant unless/until the designer says otherwise.